# sbt 0.13.16 - How do I customize triggered execution (file watch)

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.13

Right now, most of the changes that I am making are to config files and build.sbt files. That being said, I still want to trigger execution (ex. compile, test, reload, etc) when I touch these files. How do I customize sbt triggered execution to execute when any file in the project is modified?

https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Triggered.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Triggered.html

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Triggered.html

```
watchSources += baseDirectory.value
```

I just do this to watch the entire base directory:

```
watchSources := Seq(file("."))
```